# What exactly am I accessing in my code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cgpoint

Forgive my ignorance but I have a hard time remembering what I'm accessing in my code.

```
if (pos.x < leftBorderLimit)
{
pos.x = leftBorderLimit;
playerVelocity = CGPointZero; 
}

else if (pos.x > rightBorderLimit) 
{
pos.x = rightBorderLimit;
playerVelocity = CGPointZero;
}
```

Here's what I know. I know that when I do `'playerVariable.x'`(which is a CGPoint variable) I'm accessing this variables X axis and I can do whatever I want with it.. but what exactly is happening when I just do `'playerVelocity = ..... '` and what happens when I assign CGPointZero to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`playerVelocity` must be a CGPoint so that you can represent the x- and y-component of the velocity. Assigning `CGPointZero` to `playerVelocity` will set both the x and y components to 0.

Comment: Alright, makes sense. What if I did `playerVelocity.x = CGPointZero;` 
Would that set ONLY the X to zero but leave Y at whatever.. ?

Comment: No, `playerVelocity.x` is just the x component of the CGPoint, which is a single CGFloat value (i.e. a floating point number). If you want to set just the x component to 0, you do `playerVelocity.x = 0.0`

Answer (score 1):

`playerVelocity = CGPointZero;` means `playerVelocity = CGPointMake(0,0);`.